# Android ImageView hot spot mapping

Tags: android, image

I have an image of size 1024x768 where hotspots are mapped to work on 10" tablet but when I run my application on kindle fire the image size is reduced and hotspots won't work. Is there any formula to map the coordinates on a smaller image to be mapped with larger image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give enough detail to provide a precise answer.

1. What are you using to display the image?  ImageView?
2. Is the image scaled/cropped to maintain the aspect ratio?
3. Are you getting X and Y in a touch listener?
4. Are your hot spots implemented with some kind of hit tester comparing touched X,Y with the hot spot definitions?

Assuming ImageView and a touch listener getting X and Y, then you need to scale the hot spots to whatever resolution your image is shown at.  I've done this recently by extending the ImageView class and overriding the onMeasure() callback.  In onMeasure, determine whether the image is landscape or portrait then calculate the scaling factor between your images native size (the size for which you specified the hot spots) and the display size.

Something like this:

```
 if (this.getWidth() > this.getHeight()) {
     scaleFactor = ((float)this.getWidth() / (float)this.originalBitmapWidth);
 } else {
     scaleFactor = ((float)this.getHeight() / (float)this.originalBitmapHeight);
 }

 for (Hotspot hotspot : hotspots){
     hotspot.setScale(scaleFactor);
 }
```

Comment: 1. I am using ImageView to display the image.

Comment: OK.  So assume that your app is running on a device with a resolution of 512x384.  Your image will be shown at half it's native resolution (assuming full screen).  So a hit spot at 100,100 needs to be scaled to 50,50.  As width is greater than height, your scale factor is displayed width (measured in onMeasure) divided by original width = 512/1204 = 0.5.  Scale your hot spot at 100,100 by 0.5 to get 50,50.  A good solution would measure the native size of the bitmap to be fully re-usable rather than assume, and hard code, 1024x768.